# Uninstall iPython using pip on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, ipython

I wanted to uninstall iPython(v 2.3.1) from the system, so I used the following command:

```
sudo pip uninstall ipython
```

to which it said successfully uninstalled. Then when I did 'pip freeze', it showed that ipython was still installed. All it did was it downgraded ipython from v 2.3.1 to v 0.12.1. Is there something wrong that I'm doing?

Note: I don't have ipython in my requirements.txt as well.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7? Do you have any other Python 2.7 on your system? Did you install `ipython` with `pip` in the first place? How did you install `pip`? (I ask because it's weird that `ipython` would go to `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin`, and even weirder that, if it did so, the package wouldn't go into `/Library/Frameworks/Python2.7`.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if it "downgraded ipython from v 2.3.1 to v 0.12.1" that almost certainly means you had two versions installed in different ways, the packages installed to different places that are both on your `sys.path` and the executables to different places that are both on your `PATH`. So, 2.3.1 was hiding 0.12.1, and now that you've installed it, 0.12.1 is unhidden.

Answer (score 0):

> All it did was it downgraded ipython from v 2.3.1 to v 0.12.1.

That isn't possible.

---

One thing that's possible is that you installed 0.12.1 using some means other than `pip`, then forgot about it, then later installed 2.3.1 with `pip`, which ended up *hiding* the 0.12.1 rather than replacing it. So, when you uninstall 2.3.1, the 0.12.1 is unhidden and starts working again.

If that's the case, you need to *also* uninstall 0.12.1. And you're going to have to do that manually, since you didn't use `pip`, and other installers don't have uninstallers. So, first `which ipython` to see where the executable is. Then, since that's a script, `less $(which python)` and make sure its shebang line is pointing at the Python you expect. Then start Python normally, `import IPython`, and print out `IPython.__file__` to see where the package is. If it's in a .egg file, there may be a .egg-info alongside it that you'll also need to remove.

---

Another thing that's possible is that you've installed a whole other Python 2.7 alongside the one Apple gave you, and you installed 0.12.1 for one of those and 2.3.1 for the other. The steps for getting rid of 0.12.1 aren't much different, except that you're going to have to determine which Python 2.7 executable it's installed for to do the manual uninstall part.

If this is the case, I would strongly suggest that you clean things up much further. Either:

- Uninstall the non-Apple Python and just use Apple's, or
- Uninstall all site-packages you've installed for Apple's Python—especially `pip`—and never touch Apple's. (Also, get to know any differences in the banners for the Apple and non-Apple Python so you'll recognize more quickly when you accidentally do run the wrong one.)

Or, of course, you can take this as a good time to upgrade to Python 3.4, which won't conflict with Apple's because they don't supply a 3.4. :)